# Set HTTPS for Symfony via .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, symfony-2.8

I need to set HTTPS for my project based on Symfony.
In root directory, I have .htaccess with this content, because web root is not web directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
```

What do I need to set in .htaccess file (or in /web/.htaccess file) to force HTTPS?

Comment: There are millions of examples to redirect users from http to https. Why did none of all those _not_ answer your question? What sense is there in us writing that down again which you could have found with a simple search?

Comment: " in .htaccess file (or in /web/.htaccess file)" - you have two `.htaccess` files?

Comment: @w3dk Yes, first is in application root and redirect to web folder and second is in web folder and it is default Symfony file.

Answer (score 0):

In your root `.htaccess` file *before* the existing rewrites try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Change the `R` to `R=301` only when you are sure it's working OK.

NB: This makes no attempt at domain canonicalisation (ie. www or non-www?). Whatever *host* is used in the request is used in the *substitution*.

---

**UPDATE:** To help with debugging, try the following (after commenting out the above):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ /?HTTPS=%{HTTPS}&SERVER_PORT=%{SERVER_PORT} [R,L]
```

And access the document root using the HTTPS protocol, ie. `https://example.com/`. (Hopefully this doesn't conflict with your Symfony app.) 
You should see a query string of the form `/?HTTPS=on&SERVER_PORT=443` on the URL in the address bar. What do you see?

Comment: How is your SSL cert implemented? Is it installed on your server or are you using a proxy/CDN of some kind? This method (using the `HTTPS` server variable) assumes it is installed directly on your application server.

Comment: It is installed on the server. When I type address with https:// it is fine. But http is not redirected to https.

Comment: I've added some code to help with debugging to my answer. What do you see after trying this?

Comment: I see ?HTTPS=off&SERVER_PORT=80 (with https at the beginning). But when I click on green lock, ceritifcate name (and info) is correct.

Comment: In that case you must be behind some kind of proxy that manages your SSL??? If HTTPS is "off" and SERVER_PORT is 80 then your application is serving responses over HTTP. Check the request headers to your application, do you see `X-Forwarded-For` or `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP request headers?

Comment: No, there is nothing like this.

Comment: Check all the HTTP request headers that your application sees (add these to your question) and include a dump of the `$_SERVER` superglobal. If your application is serving content directly over HTTPS then there must be _something_ in that lot that indicates an HTTPS connection.